# 標準出力の内容を行ごとに2つのコマンドの引数として渡したい

Tags: bash

タイトルの通り，うまく日本語にできないので検索できず質問しています．
イメージとしては，

```
cat target.txt | grep (target.txtの各行) greped.txt | python main.py -q (target.txtの各行) | sort | python sub.py
```

のように，パイプの内容を2箇所に渡すような処理がしたいのですが，良い方法はないでしょうか？
ご教示いただければ幸いです．よろしくお願いいたします．

追記：すいません，あまりにもひどすぎました．やりたいこととしては，

```
grep　-w "hoge" large_text_data | python main.py -q "hoge"
```

こういうコマンドを，この"hoge"部分をあるファイルの各行の内容について実行したいという意味です．例としては，

```
a
b
c
```

という内容のファイルがあった時に，

```
grep　-w "a" large_text_data | python main.py -q "a"
grep　-w "b" large_text_data | python main.py -q "b"
grep　-w "c" large_text_data | python main.py -q "c"
```

という風に実行がしたい，と言いたかったのです．大変申し訳ありませんでした．

Comment: すみません、例文から正確にイメージできませんでした。
```
(パイプを含むコマンド列1) | (パイプを含むコマンド列2)
(パイプを含むコマンド列1) | (パイプを含むコマンド列3)
```
※「パイプを含むコマンド列1」は1回だけ実行される

のように、ある(パイプを含む)コマンドの実行結果を
複数のコマンドに渡すような処理を希望しているということでよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: tee コマンド + bash の process substitution や、[moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) に含まれる pee コマンド(process tee)などで対応できるかと思います。

Comment: 質問内容から察するに本来ならgrepを実行する部分で結果をgreped.txtにリダイレクトするんじゃないかと思いますが如何でしょうか。

Comment: とりあえず、パイプというやり方にこだわらず、何をしたいのか、どういう処理をしたいのか、どういう結果が要るのかなど教えてください。

Comment: 本文の編集内容に合わせてタイトルを変更しました。「言いたいことと違っている」などの問題があれば編集履歴からロールバックをお願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございます．大変助かります．編集していただいたもので問題ございません．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

表題が間違っているのか本文も不明確なのでよくわかりませんが、こういうこと?

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r arg; do
  grep -- "$arg" greped.txt |python main.py -q "$arg"
done \
<target.txt \
|sort \
|python sub.py \
;
```

追記された仕様ならば以下で:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r arg; do
  grep -w -- "$arg" greped.txt |python main.py -q "$arg"
done \
<target.txt \
;
```